# Does "loopback" in a loopback file mean the same as in loopback IP address?

Tags: loop-device, loopback

`man pvcreate` says

> pvcreate initializes a PV so that it is recognized as belonging to LVM, and allows the PV to be
>   used in a VG. A PV can be a disk partition, whole disk, meta device, or **loopback file.**

What is a loopback file? Does "loopback" in a loopback file mean the same as in loopback IP address?

Is a loopback file related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device, which I am not familiar with either?

Thanks.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/loop-device/info -- "A loop device allows any file to be mounted as a filesystem image. Not to be confused with a loopback interface in networking."

Comment: That's unrelated, it's just loop device, but I think these words ARE confusing, don't know where they come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is a loopback file?

A file that is treated as a device

> Does "loopback" in a loopback file mean the same as in loopback IP address?

No; the former is sub content the latter is a self reference.

> Is a loopback file related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device, which I am not familiar with either?

Yes.